# iPhone:Tutorial of json in ios 5

Tags: iphone, json, ios5

I am first time implementing json in my app.

and in my app I have to **pass parameters** from my app to webservice and according to that i can get response from web service but I am not able to find any tutorial in which I can pass parameters from my app in **ios5**

so is there any tutorial on net from which I can get tutorial which is useful to me.

I tried to find using google but i did not succeed.

Comment: Check out this tutorial - http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: @RIP:I have checked this tutorial but i don't know how and where  to pass parameters. In this tutorial only url is passed from the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following steps follow for the integrate the json in to our project.

1) Copy paste the below file into your project.

2) Create new Group name as help which contain the following files.

3) Create the new file into Support Files which is name as a constant.h

```
#define WEB_SERVICE_URL @"Your server url" //@"http://demo.google.com/webservice/"

#define USERNAME @"Your user id"//static username to send everytime
#define PASSWORD @"Your Password"//static password to send everytime
```

4) Change the above the variable  link where is your web service exist that means url of your webservice  ”WEB_SERVICE_URL”

5)  Open “Rest.h” file and create the one method.

```
-(void)Get_StoreDetails:(SEL)seletor andHandler:(NSObject*)handler andCountryId:(NSString *)CountryCode;
```

6) Open “Rest.m” file and which argument to pass to server that method to code.

```
-(void)Get_StoreDetails:(SEL)seletor andHandler:(NSObject *)handler andCountryId:(NSString *)country_id{
    NSDictionary *req = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"content/get_stores",@"request",
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:USERNAME,@"username",
                          PASSWORD,@"password",
                          country_id,@"country_id",
                          nil],@"para",nil];
    [[[JSONParser alloc] initWithRequest:req sel:seletor andHandler:handler] autorelease];

}
```

7) now the Rest application is ready for the send the request and then now this method call in to our view controller.

Following code put into the “viewWillAppear” method in .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface JsonDemoAppViewController : UIViewController{
    UIAlertView *alertCtr;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *arrForStores;
- (void)getData:(id)object;
@end
```

Following code put into the “viewWillAppear” method in .m file and import “Rest.h”.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.arrForStores=nil;
    //============================Json Initialization===================================================
    REST *rest = [[REST alloc] init];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [rest Get_StoreDetails:@selector(getData:) andHandler:self andCountryId:@"12"];

    alertCtr = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
    [alertCtr show];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    // Adjust the indicator so it is up a few pixels from the bottom of the alert
    indicator.center = CGPointMake(alertCtr.bounds.size.width / 2, alertCtr.bounds.size.height - 50);
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [alertCtr addSubview:indicator];
    [indicator release];
    //===================================================================================================

}
```

Then the reply comes into server that time object store into the variable that time we create the metod which calls.

```
- (void)getData:(id)object{
    NSLog(@"%@",object);
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Controll comes here..");
        //IF your response type is NSDictionary then this code to run
    }

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        self.arrForStores=[NSArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray*)object];
        //IF your response type is NSArray then this code to run
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    [alertCtr dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

}
```

[Download the source code From Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nimitparekh/files/JSON%20parsing%20Demo/JsonDemoApp.zip/download)